# Change width of one Column in Table using FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I have a dynamic PHP table which is generated on to a PDF via FPDF.

How can I make the column 'Name' wider than the others?

```
class PDF extends FPDF {
    function Header() {
        $this->Image('quote-header.png');
        $this->Ln(2);
    }

    function Footer() {
        $this->Image('quote-footer.png');
    }

    function LoadData($file) {
        $lines = file($file);
        $data = array();
        foreach($lines as $line)
        $data[] = explode(';', trim($line));
        return $data;
    }

    function BasicTable($header, $data) {
        foreach($header as $col)
        $this->Cell(40, 7, $col, 1);
        $this->Ln();
        foreach($data as $row) {
            foreach($row as $col)
            $this->Cell(40, 6, $col, 1);
            $this->Ln();
        }
    }
}

$header = array('Product Reference', 'Name', '('. $pound_sign .') Price (excl. VAT)', 'Unit');
```

I'm confident that is the only code that generates the table?

Any help would be brilliant. This is for a Product Quotation system for a company I work for and I cannot progress further without fixing this column width issue.

The table is made up of 4 columns: Product Reference, Name, Price and Unit. I need the Name column to be wider than the others, or if possible (automatically adjust) to the Product Name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter in the `Cell` method is width. http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/cell.htm

Try this to double the size.

```
function BasicTable($header, $data) {
    $nameIndex =  array_search ( 'Name' , $header );       

    foreach($header as $key => $col) {
        $width = ($key == $nameIndex) ? 80 : 40;
        $this->Cell($width, 7, $col, 1);            
    }

    $this->Ln();

    // This assumes that $row is an int indexed array
    // E.G looks like array(0 => 'some Product Reference ', 1 => 'Some Name' , 2 =>'Some Price', 3 => 'Some Unit')         
    foreach($data as $row) {
        foreach($row as $key => $col) {
            $width = ($key == $nameIndex) ? 80 : 40;
            $this->Cell($width, 6, $col, 1);
        }
        $this->Ln();
    }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, my table goes all over the place?

Comment: I cannot thank you enough. Is there anyway to limit the table width from exceeding the page margin? It would be great to have the left margin the same as the right margin.

Comment: FPDF doesn't keep track of the current position unfortunately. So in order to prevent your script from writing off of the page you need to keep track of how much you have written to each line in your loop. Where you want to stop and move down a line depends on the size of your paper, font, etc.

Comment: there is only around 10 words per row, there is nothing that would exceed the length of a page. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are only looking to add margins check out the `SetMargins` method. http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/setmargins.htm